# Can I call python script or function from php

Tags: php, python, linux

I have the php page which lists the backups with filename and username.
the backups are done with python script but for web interface I used php.

Now I want to put the facility on webpage where there will be button called restore next to backup file name and all the home dir contents are replaced.

I can make the python function with parameters like backup filename , username and it restores the backup.

But I don't know how can I pass variables to python via php

Comment: if you can call your phyton scripts from command line, you can use php [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function. You can construct the parameters in a string then pass it to the `exec()` function

Comment: posible duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697304/call-python-script-by-php-and-solve-errors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can call `exec("python pythonscript.py someparams");` or if you need to save the output to a variable use this code

```
exec("python mypythonscript.py someparams",$output);
var_dump($output);
```

More informaiton: [call python script by php and solve errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697304/call-python-script-by-php-and-solve-errors)

Comment: Can i perform python operation from inside php script rather than going through shell

Answer (score 1):

You can call the shell from PHP:

- [shell_exec()](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)
- [exec()](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)
- [backticks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)

and there are more.