# Simplest way to call a function from python script and execute in PHP

Tags: python, php, laravel, function

I'm using Laravel framework and just experimenting something.
Is there a way to use a function from a python script and use it in a PHP script?

By the way, my python script contains multiple functions.
And the function I need requires parameters.
Do I need to isolate the needed function in another script?

Please help this beginner! Thank you in Advance.

Comment: as an alternative, you could create an api for your python and for the php just simply make an http request to that api made from python, send it using post or get or json or whatever fits with your requirement

Comment: use API or create a python scripts then run it on the terminal using artisan or exec function

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094643/can-i-call-python-script-or-function-from-php

Comment: please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Create a python script to call your desired function. ([Reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm))

Look into Symfony's `Process` class. ([Reference](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html))

Use the `Process` class to run your python script:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$process = new Process(['python', 'your_script.py', 'argument1', 'argument2']);
$process->run();

if ($process->isSuccessful()) {
    $output = $process->getOutput();
    // do something with $output
} else {
    // handle failure
}
```